# Db concurrency: field vs UPDLOCK

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, commit, rollback

I'm developing an Enterprise resource planning in Omnis using SQL Server.

Multiple users will read-update-delete ecords, so i have to deal with concurrency.

I see two possible solution. And i already know how to deal with both.
I'm just asking which is better for you.

AUTOMATIC SOLUTION
Setting the transaction mode = Automatic, so the BEGIN-COMMIT-ROLLBACK transaction are automatically done by the software, but no concurrency control at all.
I could use a field on every table that contains the name of the user blocking the record, if is empty the user can update the record and i store the user name in the filed,
if the field is NOT empty i will display the user blocking the field.

MANUAL SOLUTION
Setting the transaction mode = Manual, so i have to deal with BEGIN-COMMIT-ROLLBACK, but i can use things like UPDLOCK with ROWLOCK.

Do you see the using of a field instead of UPDLOCK with ROWLOCK as a bad-poor practice?
There are other pro and cons?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not field vs UPDLOCK. The question should be what business logic is and which way you are going to make it.

Which concurrent problems do you have there exactly and how they should be solved?

What your code should be doing if there is two or more concurrent:

- inserts of the same data
- updates on the same row
- delete and update of the same row
- mb more here

Then your answer is in the following questions:
Do `AUTOMATIC SOLUTION` gonna do what you need here or no? Or you have to implement manual control?

Comment: If USER_A is updating a row, the other user can only read that row.

Comment: If they try to update or delete the same row, a message on the screen should inform that USER_A is updating that record. I need just that.

Comment: You shouldn't mess transactions with messages on the screen. You don't want transaction to be controlled by user input. Better write all "screen locking" logic in your application. Example: user editing row - write to log, second user cannot edit the row before log will be updated about row release.

Comment: You right, i will use manual mode. I will take care of begin-commit-rollback plus i'm gonna use a specific field to indicate which user is modifyng the record. Thanks